# Quadratic for two unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ x^2-ax+y^2-4y+a+20=0 $ **If the solution set has a single-element, what's the product of different values of a?**

Comment: The solution is unique iff the equation is $\left(x-\frac a2\right)^2+(y-2)^2=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$x^2-ax+y^2-4y+a+20=0$$
implies
$$\bigg(x-\frac{a}{2}\bigg)^2+(y-2)^2 = \frac{a^2-4a\color{red}{-64}}{4}.$$

Comment: Should I complete to the square number for questions like this?

Comment: @Hatm02 $(x-k)^2+(y-h)^2=C$ has only one solution when $C = 0$. You just need to find the values of $a$ for which $C=0$. There is a shortcut for finding the required product too, but I'll leave that for you to figure out.

Comment: Okay. I have now fully understood. Thanks so much.